# Add JS to specific pages if logged in

Tags: layout, javascript, update-handle

I'm writing a module containing some js that is only relevant if the user is logged in. As it is in use only on catalog_product_view & catalog_list_view I use their equivalent layout handles for now. But how can I combine these two conditions?

I know that there are the customer_logged_in/customer_logged_out handles as well as a "condition"-tag for the head-addItem method but I only found "condition=IE7" or similar

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to nest the handles just like with the `STORE_[id]` handles.

```
<customer_logged_in>
   <catalog_product_view>
      <reference name="head">
          <action method="addJs"><script>your/script.js</script></action>
      </reference>
   </catalog_product_view>
</customer_logged_in>
```